# Dificuldade ao escrever um REGEX para validar URL

Tags: javascript, java, regex, dart

Estou com dificuldade para criar uma expressão regular que valida a seguinte URL:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/nome-app/*

*seria qualquer coisa!

Alguém poderia me dar um surpote relacionado?

Comment: Coloque na pergunta apenas as tags relacionadas com o problema. Vc quer usar regex em Java, JavaScript ou Dart?

Comment: Para mim a lógica do regex é generica... pode ser em qualquer um que eu compreendo...

Comment: Já tentou isso: `https:\/\/firebasestorage.googleapis.com\/v0\/b\/nome-app\/.+`

Comment: Na verdade é melhor focar em uma linguagem específica. Regex varia muito de uma linguagem pra outra e nem sempre as soluções são iguais (nesse caso específico talvez até seja, mas nem sempre é assim)

Comment: @hkotsubo pois é. Até removi minha resposta pq achei mt inconsistente.

Comment: Não bastaria ver se a string começa com `"http://firebase...etc"`? Aí nem precisa de regex, toda linguagem possui um método similar a `startsWith` para strings...

Answer (score 1):

Está aqui como podes fazer :)

```
if (a_tua_variavel.indexOf('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/nome-app/') > -1){
   alert("Tem parte do link");
}
```